# EditText in ListView loses content on scroll in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I'm working on an app where users fill reports and polls. In an activity I have a ListView where children contain EditTexts, Checkbox and TextView.

The problem with EditTexts and Checkbox was that when scrolling, the content that they have is lost. I was able to fix the Checkbox problem by saving the check status in an array, but I can't fix the problem with EditTexts. I know that there are some questions about this particular issue but the solutions that they provided doesn't seem to work. So here is my adapter:

```
public class DiveProfileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DiveProfile> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<DiveProfile> mTasks;
    ViewHolder holder;

    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<>(); //for saving checkbox values

    public DiveProfileAdapter(Context context, List<DiveProfile> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_dive_profile_divers_list_item, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mTasks = objects;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
        }
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dive_profile_divers_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.diverAttended = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.diver_attended_checkbox);   
            holder.diveTime = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dive_time_edit_text);
            holder.depth = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.depth_edit_text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final DiveProfile diverObjectTask = mTasks.get(position);

        holder.diverAttended.setChecked(diverObjectTask.isDiverAttended());
        holder.diveTime.setText(diverObjectTask.getDiveTime());

        holder.diverAttended.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.diver_attended_checkbox);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked.set(position, true);
                    // do some operations here
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                   itemChecked.set(position, false);
                   // do some operations here
                }
             }
        });
        holder.diverAttended.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position)); // this will Check or Uncheck the

        holder.diveTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt = setDiveTimeDialog();
                holder.diveTime.setText(txt);
                mTasks.get(position).setCurrentText(txt); //add the setter to the current item's position
            }
        });
        holder.diveTime.setText(diverObjectTask.getCurrentText());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox diverAttended;
        EditText diveTime;
        EditText depth;
    }

    private String setDiveTimeDialog() {

        //final String[] items = finItems;
        final String[] items = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.certification_level_items);

        // Create list dialog with required parameters - context, title, and our array of items to fill the list.
        CustomListDialog.Builder builder = new CustomListDialog.Builder(getContext(), "Dive Time", items);

        // Now again we can use some extra methods on the builder to customise it more.
        builder.titleAlignment(BaseDialog.Alignment.LEFT);
        builder.itemAlignment(BaseDialog.Alignment.LEFT);
        builder.titleColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_color));


        // Now we can build our dialog.
        CustomListDialog customListDialog = builder.build();

        // Finally we can show it.
        customListDialog.show();

        customListDialog.setListClickListener(new CustomListDialog.ListClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onListItemSelected(int i, String[] strings, String s) {

                result = s;

            }
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: where you have set the text for editText??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this :

```
final DiveProfile diverObjectTask = mTasks.get(position);
holder.diveTime.setText(diverObjectTask.getDiveTie());
//also set your CheckBox value
```

Those values become empty because you dont set it in the `getView` (`getView` automatically getting called when the list scrolled)

**UPDATE**

Looking at your problem, i think the easiest way is to create new variables in `DiveProfile` class, such as `boolean isSelected` and `String currentText`.

After that, theres no need to use separate list like `itemChecked`. You can `get` and `set` the current item's value.

Example for using `getter`:

```
holder.diverAttended.setChecked(mTasks.get(position).getSelected()); // getSelected is isSelected getter method
```

And call `setSelected` (`setter` of `isSelected`) in your `holder.diverAttended` `onClick`

Example for your `EditText` `setter` :

```
    holder.diveTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String txt = setDiveTimeDialog();
            holder.diveTime.setText(txt);
            mTasks.get(position).setcurrentText(txt); //add the setter to the current item's position
        }
    });
```

And call `getCurrentText()` in the `getView`

Comment: I already have that but it's not working. So I decided to simplify the code here in StackOverflow.

Comment: @user2033242 Please post your code that not working, its the most important code in your case :) Tips : Make sure you have both `if-else` for the conditions

Comment: @user2033242 you dont have `holder.diveTime.setText` in your `getView`, you only have that in the `onClick`. You should have both

Comment: I have it in onClick because a dialog opens and user selects one of the options. If I do `holder.diveTime.setText(setDiveTimeDialog());` outside the onClick then the dialog will open for all the items. If I just do `holder.diveTime.setText(diverObjectTask.getDiveTime());` - it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user2033242 Please see my updated answer. Please take your time to understand it, i tried my best to explain it with example :)

Comment: Yes the values are being saved now but I need to double click the EditText field so the `holder.diveTime.setText(txt);` to work. Once to select the options from the dialog box and as soon as I click the view again it gets the respective value, otherwise If I don't click it again, it stays empty!

Comment: @user2033242 Great, we are getting there. Please post your current code :)

Comment: @user2033242 you forgot to call the setter of `isSelected` in `if (cb.isChecked())` inside `onClick` and try to change `mTasks.get(position).setcurrentText(txt);` to `diverObjectTask.setcurrentText(txt);`

Comment: @user2033242 Great..one problem left. Try to use `diverObjectTask.setcurrentText(txt);`. If its not working, try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` after that.

Comment: your solution is working great but the problem is with the dialog box (L-Dialogs library). I tried some Logs and when the method `setDiveTimeDialog();` is called, the code is not pausing to wait for me to select one of the options from the dialog but continues executing the other part of `onClick` so the `String txt` value is still null. That's why when I click the  second time, `String txt` has the value from the previous run and then it just sets it in the EditText.

Comment: @user2033242 Great :) Sorry i never use that library. Feel free to create a new question with new your current code :)

Comment: no thank you VERY MUCH for helping me through this. What I did is copy/pasted the whole content of `setDiveTimeDialog()` inside the `onClick` method and forced `diveTime.setText(txt);` to wait until the selection is done. It is working great :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Viewholder variable must be inside your getView, preferrably the first variabe you declare right before if(convertView). Caching the ViewHolder outside will cause unpredictable behavior.

ConvertView is the View returned, so you have to set whatever changes you make onto the convertview.

Comment: Ok, I edited my code with your suggestion but still not working in this case.

Comment: In your onClick you create a new CheckBox, do something with it, then never add it to your convertview, which loads the old one. You should just use the one you retrieved from getTag() instead and do your manipulations on the convertView's checkboxes.

Comment: You should probably watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 because I don't know how much you know about how adapters work.